# String and Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression

Tags: javascript

I have this code, where `getURLParamter` returns the value of a url parameter and I use that value to select on an input.

```
var urlParam   = getURLParameter('a'),
    selectedInput   = $('input[id="custom-156[' + urlParam + ']"');
```

This has worked without problem through many rounds of cross-browser testing. However, there have been sporadic error reports from users including, finally, a co-worker. Chrome's console showed this error:

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: input[id="custom-156[1]"
```

My coworker uses the same model computer and the same version of Chrome. I don't have this error but he does. Why would this be and what is the cause of the error? I think it is a problem with the single double quotes within the pair of single quotes. What is a better way to write this?

Comment: There is no closing square bracket on the selector.  you'll need ```input[id="custom-156[' + urlParam + ']"]'```

Comment: Thanks! I need glasses. Why don't you add this as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no closing square bracket on the selector. you'll need

```
input[id="custom-156[' + urlParam + ']"]'
```

For the points ;)